# Android 2.1 browser not loading css for mobile site

Tags: css, loading, mobile-website, android-2.1-eclair

I have created a mobile site which uses django for the backend. 
The content is very simple and I am loading a simple css file around 12kb and four javascript files (total size 120kb).

When I start navigating in the website the css loads correctly but after navigating back and forth to some pages the css stops loading.

However, when working on my computer (with wamp and localhost) and browsing the website with my mobile from the same network everything works fine.

The problem only occurs when browsing the site with my mobile form my real server, and only with the browser of Android 2.1 (Android 2.3 and safari mobile work fine).

Any idea what might cause this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found out what was wrong with this in case anyone else needs it. The server was asking for a password there was a bug connected with this and the android browser